# Space not freed after removing Matlab

Tags: 14.04, matlab

I removed Matlab 2014a Application in Linux Ubuntu 14.04 which is located in the following folder:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/
```

However, I found that the available space is still the same. Is there anything more I need to do in-order to free some space on the disk?

Comment: How did you remove? Did you moved it to the trash?

Comment: No, I removed it using command line rm -rf

Comment: I find this implausible. Can you prove that the available space indeed remains the same?